# Could use an explanation with a classes and elements CSS code

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I was just wondering how to view p.intro::first-letter in the following code.  Does this mean that only in a p element can the intro class be used?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.intro::first-letter {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 200%;
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="intro">This is an introduction.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text. A bit more text even.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use all classes wherever you want, the CSS will only apply to some of them though.

Comment: Given there is a p alongside the .intro yes it will as it stands work only on p elements. However there is nothing to stop you defining for example *.intro::first-letter instead to get every element (for which first-letter makes sense) to make its first character red and larger. Or if you only want it to work with divs say, use div.intro::first-letter

Answer (score 1):

Yes
The selector `p.intro::first-letter` means "Style the `::first-letter` of a `<p>` element with the class `intro`.

When there is no space between the selectors `p`, `.intro`, `::first-letter` (these are called selectors) it is like an "AND" statement

`div.RedText` means `div` element AND `RedText` class

It's worth reading up on the [different types of selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), W3Schools has a [really good interactive example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp) too!

Here's a little more:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p.intro::first-letter {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 200%;
      }
      div {
        color: #0000ff;
      }
      div.RedText {
        color: #ff0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p class="intro">This is an introduction.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph with some text. A bit more text even.</p>
    <div>This text is blue</div>
    <div class="RedText">This text is red!</div>

  </body>
</html>
```